# Possible Prime Sum Pattern (Amateur)

Tags: prime-numbers, pattern-recognition

Disclaimer: I’m an amateur, and have no advanced knowledge of math, so please forgive my ignorance as I’m just curious to know if I’ve stumbled upon something or not.

Prime Numbers:

*2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109*

Applying the prime numbers to the list of prime numbers yields the following when they are aligned:

*3, 5, 11, 17, 31, 41, 59, 67, 83, 109*

- 3 is the **2nd** prime
- 5 is the **3rd** prime
- 11 is the **5th** prime
- 17 is the **7th** prime
- 31 is the **11th** prime
- 41 is the **13th** prime
- 59 is the **17th** prime
- 67 is the **19th** prime
- 83 is the **23rd** prime
- 109 is the **29th** prime

So three is the first in our new list because it is the 2nd prime and 2 is our first prime number.

Then by adding the original list of primes up until each of the new primes in our list we are left with this:

2 + 3 = **5**

2 + 3 + 5 = **10**

2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 11 = **28**

2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 11 + 13 + 17 = **58**

2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 11 + 13 + 17 + 19 + 23 + 29 + 31 = **160**

Next five sums are:  **238, 440, 568, 696,** and **1002**

Question: Will this pattern always produce an even sum?

Comment: Yes. Every prime greater than two is odd, and so there are an even number of primes added at each step you take. Since all of the primes greater than two are odd, you are adding an even number of odd numbers, which will always be even, and adding this even number to the even number that you had before still leaves an even number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice you keep adding two primes at a time. All primes, except for $2$, are odd. The sum of two odd numbers is even. Then you add the first prime, $2$, which is even, meaning the sum is still even. So you will always end up with an even sum.

P.S. Keep up with your investigations! The deepest understanding of Mathematics comes from playing around with things yourself and looking for patterns, asking your own questions, and exploring the subject in your own way.

Comment: Thanks! Will do.

Does this mean that every prime in this pattern is an even distance away from the next? (minus 3 and 5)

Comment: The primes aren't really involved in this pattern, their sum is. If you are asking are primes always an even distance from each other then the answer is yes, kind of. The distance from $2$ to $3$ is odd but after that the distance from one prime to the next must be even. Because each prime after $2$ is odd, if the distance to the next prime were odd we would have prime$+$distance$=$next prime which we would have odd+odd$=$next prime, but odd and odd makes even, which can't happen because we know the new prime must be odd. So the distance between all primes, except for $2$ and $3$, is even.

Comment: Got it. You've been a great help.

Comment: So, because I'm adding a prime number of primes each set is an odd number, but subtract the number 2 and I'm left with an even number of odd numbers, which is always even. (except for 3 and 5)

Comment: No, you keep add two primes at a time to your previous sums. Primes (except $2$) are odd. The sum of two odds is even. So the sum will always be even, even if you add $2$ to the list because of course $2$ is even.

Comment: Yeah I meant the same thing, just from a different perspective. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, what you said was just backwards from what I said (you went backwards, I went forwards) except for where you said 'adding a prime number of primes'. You are adding an even amount of primes (excluding two) whose sum is even.